# Optimize volume of sphere+cube, surface are known

Tags: calculus, optimization

If the total surface area of a sphere and a cube is 1 square meter, what dimensions should the two solids be to make the total volume of them a maximum?

Answer (score 1):

The surface areas combine to make the constraint:

$$6 a^2 + 4 \pi r^2 = 1$$

where $a$ is the side of the cube and $r$ is the radius of the sphere.  Use this to maximize

$$V(a) = a^3 + \frac{4 \pi}{3} r(a)^3$$

where $r=r(a)$ is determined form the surface area constraint.  You maximize by taking the derivative of $V$ and setting it to zero:

$$V'(a) = 3 a^2 + 4 \pi r(a)^2 r'(a) = 0$$

Comment: What's the last a in V(a)=a^3+(4π/3)*r(a)³ ?

Comment: $r$ as a function of $a$; you find this form the first equation.